# In TextEdit, if I type two `-` it is converted to one longer `-`

Tags: macos, text-editor, textedit

I use TextEdit to edit my text.

If I type in a double `-`, it is converted to one longer `-`.

[image]

How to avoid this?

Comment: I  noticed this in Notes as well!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to Edit → Substitutions and disable Smart Dashes.

[image]

You can disable this globally in System Preferences: Keyboard → Text. Disable ‘Use smart quotes and dashes’.

[image]

To only disable the dash substitution globally whilst leaving smart quotes enabled by adding the substitution to System Preferences: Keyboard → Text. Add a new entry set to `--` for both ‘replace’ and ‘with’ to disable the substitution. This works because entries here override the OS regardless of whether substitutions are enabled.

[image]

To disable the dash substitution globally without this workaround, you can disable NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled:

```
defaults write -g NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In TextEdit, the solution given by [grg's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/285352/100490) only works on a per-document basis.

The disable this for *all* documents you need to go to the menu **TextEdit** ► **Preferences** and disable it there, under **Options**:

[image: TextEdit preferences dialog]